# Moving a VirtualBox .vdi Linux machine to a new host computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I've been happily using an Ubuntu 12.04 VM as a webserver with a static IP running on VirtualBox on my Windows 7 machine for a few months (working on it from the host computer, bridged network connection, accessing via SSH from host and sharing folders through windows).

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, I've got:

```
address 192.168.1.112
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 194.168.4.100 194.168.8.100
```

I tried creating a new VM with it on my Win7 laptop by copying across the .vdi and creating a new VirtualBox machine with it, then changing the static IP to `192.168.1.116`, but I'm not getting any network... It can't ping anything, when I try to SSH into the VM, it says "connection rejected" and it doesn't show up anywhere in my Windows network.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 1):

"Perryg" on the VirtualBox forums solved it:

> Edit the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, or you can delete the rules and Linux will configure it on the next boot.

That's all there was to it.